# Google Play console 64 Bit error when the game is 64 bit

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-console

Google Play console is giving error to my 64 bit app bundle file.

I build the game using unity 2019.2.1 and unity 2018.4.2 LTS and from both version i made the 64 bit version in app bundle formate. The things were working perfectly before but suddenly google is giving me error that its not 64 bit.

I want my game to be published on google play console and dont want those error as I make it completely 64 Bit Compatible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [APKs or App Bundles are available to 64-bit devices, but they only have 32-bit native code Unity Play store error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57621520/apks-or-app-bundles-are-available-to-64-bit-devices-but-they-only-have-32-bit-n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, Just Deselect the intel x86 from target build then it will work perfectly.

Answer (score -1):

having the same error, all of a sudden - have no idea wtf happened...